# Sending parameter to webservice

Tags: ios, objective-c, web-services

I need to send french string **"Commentaire d’arret"** to `webservice` in `objective c`. 
But my app crashes when I am sending this string as parameter to service. And normal string like **"india"** is working fine.

Can any one help me.

Comment: Try to escape the single quote.

Comment: No, I need to send exact string to service.

Comment: you need to change in your backend webservice, try to use "real escape string" in php, while you are passing ' with your string which is breaking the sql query so it is not working. if you want to cross check then try to send "Commentaire d arret" as an parameter it will work.

Comment: By escaping, I mean prefixing the character with an arbitrary character which prevents it to be taken literally.

Comment: Can you show some code?

Comment: ok, see this french keyword "consultés", this one I need to send post parameter to webservice.

NSString *searchApi = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://xxx/xxx/index?q=@"consultés"];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:searchApi];

In URL I am getting nil,

If I am sending "india" as keyword its working.

Comment: Please write the code in objective c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Encode your parameter for a GET request:

```
let param = "Commentaire d’arret"
let encodedParam = (param as NSString).addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)
```

Results in *Commentaire%20d%E2%80%99arret*.

If you want to send a POST request prepare your post body like this:

```
let postString = "param=consultés"
let postData = postString.data(using: .utf8)
```

**Objective-C**

```
NSString *param = @"Commentaire d’arret";
NSString *encodedParam = [param stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet]];

NSString *postString = @"param=consultés";
NSData *postData = [postString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: Glad I could help.

Answer (score -1):

As you said I have checked your code and you need to do encoding before converting to your URL. try this.

```
NSString *searchApi = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"xxx/xxx/index?
q=@consultés"];
searchApi = [searchApi stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSURL *tempURL = [NSURL URLWithString:searchApi];
```

Comment: If I encoded that string, i am getting another result. Not proper result from my server.

Comment: you need to decode that string at your server side and based on that need to give response.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
NSString *strParam = @"Commentaire d’arret";
NSString *encodedParam = [strParam stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet]];
```